# fire app builder not running API videos, only raw urls

Tags: url, amazon-fire-tv, raw

In my amazon fire app builder starter kit, I have already tested changing the default lightcast.com/api/... urls to play different video files, but they have to be the raw video file (direct .mp4 file url). I want to play videos that I access through a API, but the problem is that they are not direct. How can i do this?

Comment: What's the format of your api response? Can you share it here?

Comment: i want to use this url for example: https://vidsrc.to/embed/movie/385687. i can get it s id number through java API call. this example is written in python:
import requests
API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxx'
def search_movies_and_tv(query):
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi?api_key={API_KEY}&query={query}')
    print(response.json() if response.status_code == 200 else f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    query = input("Enter the name of the movie or TV show: ")
    search_movies_and_tv(query)

Comment: however the format is in json:

Comment: You may need to deserialize the json and extract the video url